# Pubnub here_now security

Tags: pubnub

Im wondering how to deal with the here_now method from pubnub in terms of security.

I created a chat which its subscribed to 2 channels with pubnub, a unique channel for the user to receive messages, and a common channel where my server is subscribed, and verifying the presences in that channel. The problem i see here, is that a random user just with the common channel name can get all of the users online in that moment. and subcribe with one of thoses uuid, preteding that another user is online.
Is there a way to manage that?

Comment: Hi @cri_sys the quick answer is **`yes`**  You can manage access to this API via PubNub Access Manager: http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/security/ - or you can disable it by contacting support@pubnub.com to prevent access to anyone completely.

Comment: But as far as i know the PAM would help me with the read and write permissions, but not with a specific method.. so i want the clients to subscribe, but i dont want them to be able to here_now. is nt like that?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, please contact us at support@pubnub.com and we'll help you restrict what you need as fine grained as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage access to this API with [PubNub's Access Manager](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security). Basically, you would only allow authenticated users into your system, then authorize them access to certain channels. So you at least narrow it down to registered users that have been authenticated and authorized.

You could provide logic in your presence callback that alerts a user when someone joins a channel with the same UUID. It could just be the same user legitimately on two different devices but embedding this alert would allow the user to know when this is happening.